# How to get the json message from local using xamarin cross platform development

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to get the json data from local like sampledata.json using xamarin cross platform development.

Comment: From application folder?

Comment: yes ,application folder have sampledata.json

Comment: [egor-gromadskiy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5912513/egor-gromadskiy) your article was also helped

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
Type classType = typeof(Yourclassnamehere); 
TypeInfo classTypeInfo = classType.GetTypeInfo();
Assembly assemblyType = classTypeInfo.Assembly;
System.IO.Stream stream = assemblyType.GetManifestResourceStream(classType.Namespace + ".sampledata.json");
System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream);
string json = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: `    #region How to load an Json file embedded resource
   var assembly = typeof(LoadResourceJson).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
   Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("WorkingWithFiles.PCLJsonResource.json");

   Employee[] Employees;


   using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
   {

    var json = reader.ReadToEnd();
    var rootobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);

                Employees = rootobject.Employees;
   }
   #endregion

   var listView = new ListView();
   listView.ItemsSource = Employees;  `

Comment: **System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: stream** this as the error